# Best representation when we need users to pick only Sundays of every week as date

Tags: dates

I have a date input field and it should only display Every Sunday for next one year for user selection.

How can we effectively design this?

Comment: Do they get to choose a specific Sunday, one or more?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply show a date-picker dialog which has only dates falling on Sundays as enabled. And rest of the dates should appear disabled (still visible) and also communicate to user why they cannot select those (via a hover tooltip).

This approach is in sync with [Jakob Nielsen's 10 Usability Heuristics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visibility-system-status/)!